# "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: view must not be null" Program Closes when navigated

Tags: android-studio, imageview

The app closes whenever I navigate to ProfileActivity.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: hfad.com.hallofmemesprototype, PID:
>   19092 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{hfad.com.hallofmemesprototype/hfad.com.hallofmemesprototype.Profile.ProfileActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: view must not be null

Here's the "ProfileActivity" code.

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final int ACTIVITY_NUM = 3;

private Context mContext = ProfileActivity.this;

private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
private ImageView profilePhoto;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
    setupBottomNavigationView();
    setupToolbar();
    setupActivityWidgets();
    setProfileImage();
}

private void setProfileImage(){
    String imgURL = "www.androidzone.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/android-musical2.jpg";
    UniversalImageLoader.setImage( imgURL, profilePhoto, mProgressBar, "https://");
}

private void setupActivityWidgets(){
    mProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.profileProgressBar);
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    profilePhoto = findViewById(R.id.profile_photo);
}

private void setupToolbar() {
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.profileToolBar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ImageView profileMenu = findViewById(R.id.profileMenu);
    profileMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, AccountSettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

/**
 * BottomNavigationView setup
 */
private void setupBottomNavigationView() {
    BottomNavigationViewEx bottomNavigationViewEx = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavViewBar);
    BottomNavigationViewHelper.bottomNavigationView(bottomNavigationViewEx);
    BottomNavigationViewHelper.enableNavigation(mContext, bottomNavigationViewEx);
    Menu menu = bottomNavigationViewEx.getMenu();
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(ACTIVITY_NUM);
    menuItem.setChecked(true);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You must check that all the views that you are getting using `findViewById()` really exist into the `activity_profile.xml` layout.

One or more views doesn´t really exist, and you have a null value gettin the reference.

```
 findViewById(R.id.profileProgressBar);
 findViewById(R.id.profile_photo);
 findViewById(R.id.profileToolBar);
 findViewById(R.id.profileMenu);
 findViewById(R.id.bottomNavViewBar);
```

initially you are not getting any error tryin to find the references of this views because they are really exist but in another layout but not in `activity_profile.xml` that you are loading via `setContentView()` in your Activity.

Answer (score 0):

This type of exception rise at the time of the wrong variable declaration and 
initialization.

**Try this**

replace your weighs declare and initialize val with var.

**If you have to use java**

```java
final TextView helloTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view_id);
```

**For Kotlin**

```
val helloTextView = findViewById(R.id.text_view_id) as TextView
```

you can refer [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/widget/TextView.html) link for more details